# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context using array_walk

Tags: php, arrays, class

I have made a class that should replace data at the hand of an array.

I insert

```
$data = array(
                'bike',
                'car',
                'pc'
            );
```

And it should translate the array to :

```
$data = array(
                '[@bike]',
                '[@car]',
                '[@pc]'
            );
```

I have written the following piece of code.

```
array_walk($PlaceHolders , function(&$value, $key) { $value = $this->Seperators['plcstart'].$value.$this->Seperators['plcend']; });
```

Which I am using in a class context.

The two sperators have the following value:

```
$this->Seperators['plcstart'] = '[@';
$this->Seperators['plcend']   = ']';
```

The problem is. At localhost it works superb!!
Now when I upload the system to a unix environment it stops working!
I have no clue why this is the result.

Would anyone here know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Start by considering the different versions of PHP that are running on your development/localhost environment and on your production environment.... and consider why they are different when they shouldn't be

Comment: array_walk won't invoke your object, the function you're defining as the callback won't be a method of your object either. it's just a plain regular function, and $this won't be available.

Comment: Where and how are the values of `$this->Seperators` defined? Is all this defined within a class method?

Comment: The $this->Seperators are defined within the class. I think it might be a good idea to set the Seperators in a loose variable. $Start = $this->Seperators['plcstart']; etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) when you want to modify array elements using a callback.

You could end with something like this

```
class TransformerClass {
    private $Seperators = array(
        'plcstart' => '[@',
        'plcend' => ']'
    );

    public function transform(array $data) {
        return array_map(
            function($text) {
                return $this->Seperators['plcstart'].$text.$this->Seperators['plcend'];
            },
            $data
        );
    }
}
```

Example:

```
$transformer = new TransformerClass();

$items = array(
    'bike',
    'car',
    'pc'
);

$result = $transformer->transform($items);
```

And `$result` will contain your desired resulting data.

Answer (score 0):

The most bizare thing is... This morning I opened the same page again.
And it worked like the offline environment :-S....

This is quite frustrating though!!

However I would like to make a few small notes:

> ```
>   ///######## LOADING ALL PLACEHOLDERS
>   $PlaceHolders   = array_keys($this->TplObjects);
>
>   ///######## SEPERATOR START
>   $SeperatorStart = $this->Seperators['plcstart'];
>   $SeperatorEnd   = $this->Seperators['plcend'];
>
>   ///######## ADDING THE START AND END TAGS TO EACH ARRAY VALUE
>   array_walk($PlaceHolders , function(&$value, $key) { $value =
>   $SeperatorStart.$value.$SeperatorEnd; });
> ```

This is what I thought to be a solution but it is **NOT!!**
Why?? Because the way it was worked:

```
    ///######## LOADING ALL PLACEHOLDERS
    $PlaceHolders = array_keys($this->TplObjects);
    ///######## ADDING THE START AND END TAGS TO EACH ARRAY VALUE
    array_walk($PlaceHolders , function(&$value, $key) { $value = $this->Seperators['plcstart'].$value.$this->Seperators['plcend']; });
```

Because it got it's data directly out of the class.
By using *function* I placed the variables into it's own individual scope, hence the variable **$SeperatorStart** and **$SeperatorEnd** do not exist in this scope.

I could ofcourse import these two into that function. But I do not know how to do this with *array_walk*. I have not used this function this often hence I know only a few basic manners to use this function.

The second option as opted for above by **@Falc** works great! And is the method I was looking for. Hence thanks a million!!